# Glade GUI builder: setting button widget resource

Tags: gtk, ubuntu-12.04, glade

Folks,

I spent the last couple of hours playing with Glade (3.12.1) on a newly install Ubuntu (12.04 and GTK+3).

I can't understand why I don't have the ability to change the background or foreground color of a button in Glade.

Have I missed something?

Using Glade and then having to augment the code that Glade produces (first taking it from XML -> c/python/PHP/) seems to negate the benefits of using a GUI builder.

A troll through the various forums leads me to believe there has been a major change between version 2 and 3. It seem GTK+3 will be/is using CSS to set a widget's/overall GUI application's style. However, I can't find any documentation on how to integrate/include CSS and Glade in defining the style of the GUI being build in Glade.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated...